# Firestore collection document not saving after entering document id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

[image]

As per the reference image attached, am trying to create a new document, but for some reason, the save button is disabled even though all. fields are filled.

Is there anything else I need to do for the button to be enabled?

Comment: What's the ID card like icon after document ID? Not sure if there's any A/B test on there but I can just see 'Auto-ID' button which disappears when I click it.

Comment: This happened to me too, but it worked after refreshing the page...

Comment: @Dharmaraj the card like icon is embedded by lastpass extension.

Comment: @NoobLife refreshing the page actually worked!!

Comment: Nice to hear that the issue got resolved, it will be helpful for the community members if you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this was to refresh the page and ensure that the Document ID exists before adding any field.

Thanks to @prabir in the post comment.